# extract json string values in a panda column into a new columns with dynamic key in the first level

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

Hi I have a very large dataset in csv file, which I read into a panda dataframe. One column has json strings that I want to extract the values into new columns. The pic below shows a few rows in my csv file.

[image: this is example of my csv datafile.]

The fourth column (data) is the one required to be extracted. The key in the first level (605,254,834,265 etc) is always changing but the number is always the same as that in the last column ('reg'). I want to extract the values of 'price', 'status' and '#result' and put them in new columns.

The code I am using is

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json
from pandas import DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
df["result"]=np.nan #create empty column
df["price"]=np.nan
df["status"]=np.nan
for i in range (0,len(df['data'])):
      df['result'].iloc[i]=json.loads(df['data'].iloc[i])[str(df['reg'].iloc[i])]['#result']
      df['price'].iloc[i]=json.loads(df['data'].iloc[i])[str(df['reg'].iloc[i])]['price']
      df['status'].iloc[i]=json.loads(df['data'].iloc[i])[str(df['reg'].iloc[i])]['status']

print(df)
```

So I got the dataframe with new columns (result, price and status) as below:

[image]

The code gives me the output that I want. However since i am using 'for loop' it takes very long to run for the big dataframe. I think there must be a more clever way doing this. And I know that there are different ways to do if the first level key is constant. Can anyone have a better idea to extract this type of json strings in panda frame. 
Cheers!

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question), better is sample data in text version.

Answer (score 6):

In your example you're parsing the same JSON multiple times. It's enough to parse it only once. For example:

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = '{"605":{"price":"570", "address":"946", "status": "done", "#result":"good" }}'
d2 = '{"254":{"price":"670", "address":"300", "status": "done", "classification_id": "102312321", "#result":"good" }}'

df = pd.DataFrame({'num': [1771, 905],
                  'item': ['orange', 'mango'],
                  'id': [190384, 2500003],
                  'data':[d1, d2],
                  'reg': [605, 254]
    })


import json
df = df.join( pd.DataFrame(list(json.loads(d).values())[0] for d in df.pop('data')) )

# drop columns we don't want
del df['address']
del df['classification_id']

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    num    item       id  reg price status #result
0  1771  orange   190384  605   570   done    good
1   905   mango  2500003  254   670   done    good
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Andrej Kesely. This is exactly what I need. Now the script is much faster. Cheers!